# How to test for am or pm?

Tags: android

I am trying to test for am or pm in a if else statement..

```
if(am){
//Do something
else{

//Do something else
```

Ive tried

```
int am = cld.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
```

but the if else

wont take it as a parameter to test. Maybe because its not boolean.

How would i go about testing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that the if-else won't accept it because it is not boolean. `Calendar.AM_PM` only ever holds the value `0` or `1`. A language like C would accept 0 or 1 as boolean; Java won't.

You want to do something more like this:

```
int am = cld.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
if (am == 0) {
    // Do whatever for the AM
} else {
    // Do whatever because it must be PM
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely your if clause cannot accept integer as it is. You need something (comparison perhaps) to get boolean out of it.

```
   if(am > 0)
    {
      //its PM
    else { //its AM }
```

Comment: whats the 0 mean? what does it compare am against?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#AM 

Thats why 0, AM constant value is 0.

Answer (score 0):

`Calendar.AM_PM` is an int. To evaluate it in an `if` statement, cast it to a boolean:

```
if((bool)am) {
   //It's AM
} else {
   //It's PM
}
```